# "Any viable options" instead of "any viable option"

Tags: grammar, determiners

I used ChatGPT and I was surprised that it generated the sentence:

> If there are any viable options, we should carefully weigh each one
> before making a decision.

Shouldn't it be always singular when we use any? I find it weird. I thought you would say "If there's any viable option".

In this phrase, 'are' is used with the plural noun 'options,' which aligns with conventional grammar rules. However, since 'any' is a determiner that often precedes singular nouns, there is a potential conflict in number agreement.

Comment: Where did you get the information that **any** can only be used with singular nouns?  That's not correct. It can be used with singular or plural nouns. For example: "Are there any people who can help?", or "Is there any person who can help?"

Comment: I saw people using it like that, but I always thought it was a grammar error somehow.

Answer (score 1):

"Any" could refer to multiple options in that sentence. It can be used as *any one*, but here, it is used as *any of a set*.

E.G. "Are there *any* numbers greater than 17?" is valid English, though the answer would be, "Infinitely many."